# Bad practice to continue with value set in catch block?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am using something like this in my code:

```
//some code that gets the group, etc.

Point3d rotationPoint;
try
{
    rotationPoint = GetRotationPoint(group) // Throws NoDataFoundException
}
catch(NoDataFoundException)
{
    rotationPoint = RequestRotationPoint(); // Let user pick the rotation point instead
}

//...and then simply continue the method
```

The reason for this approach is I can't check whether the `rotationPoint` is `null` because it is a `struct`.
Would there be an alternative?

Comment: maybe Nullable<T>? but a flag seems like the most logical choice

Comment: If I find myself using `try ... catch` to do something I would normally use `if ... else` for, I generally take it as a sign that I need to stop and rethink my code.

Comment: @MethodMan - exceptions are very slow compared to other code. Constructing one is expensive so should be avoided for general logic flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
But why the votes down? If you do vote down can you at least give some feedback on what's wrong with the question?

Comment: @Ian I totally agree I was just confused when reading the comment initially not a big deal though

Comment: @MethodMan I mean, in general, if I am using a `try catch` block not strictly to check for an error, but to control program flow in a situation where I would normally use an `if else` block (say, a null check), I usually need to rethink what I have written and find a better way to do things.  Not always, but most of the time.

Comment: @PaulGriffin it's cool like I said it was confusing at first when reading.. I am not mad at  cha..

Comment: Ain't no thing, man.  Better to clarify if it is confusing :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bad practise, but it's actually down to the fact that you're using Exceptions for handling logic in the system, not that you're repeating a similar operation. Exceptions are supposed to be that `Exceptional` in that you weren't really expecting them, so you'll present to the user nicely and try to continue or fail gracefully.

In this case what you'd really want to do is something along the lines of the `TryParse` approach:

```
 Point3d rotationPoint;
 if(GetRotationPoint(group, out rotationPoint) == false)
 {
    rotationPoint = RequestRotationPoint();
 }
```

**Edit**

I should add, the reason that Exceptions are bad practice for doing this sort of thing is because it is an expensive operation to construct and throw an exception which can cause performance bottlenecks in your code. Often it isn't something you need to worry about, but sometimes it is - and if you've started building down that road it can be difficult to back up from.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.
Thanks for the detailed answer, Ian.

Comment: @MikeDelta No problem - as an aside no idea why your question was down-voted. I don't see anything particularly wrong with it, but I can at least cast my +1 stick on it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an acceptable approach for situations when you have no control over the `GetRotationPoint` API. When you own the API, restructuring it the "[dictionary style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)" would let you avoid using exceptions altogether:

```
Point3d rotationPoint;
if (!TryGetRotationPoint(group, out rotationPoint)) {
    rotationPoint = RequestRotationPoint(); 
}
```